# Mapbox GL JS : Fullscreen and GPS button Issues in Chrome only

Tags: javascript, geospatial, mapbox-gl-js

I am working on a weather visualization project using Mapbox (3 panes are locked together and one is for navigation, it's hard to explain until you see the link.)

Before I continue, I will post a link to the web app I am discussing here, so you can see it. My code is a MESS, and I am aware of that, but I believe this is a browser issue.

http://ability.a2hosted.com/main.html

In Edge and Firefox, the fullscreen and navigation buttons work fine. In Chrome, they do not work...  the fullscreen button gets the browser stuck until you press escape (and doesn't render properly anyway!). And, in fact, chrome does not even display the navigation button at all.

Is there a way to get these buttons to show up and function as they do in firefox and edge? Or, maybe an alternate button? I am attaching a screenshot of how the page should look.

I should note, I can live without the fullscreen buttons, but I need the navigation button option to be working in chrome. This really is a must for my project, so even if there's another link or  button I could place over it to activate it somehow, it's fine as long as it works. I am not good enough with JS to understand what may be causing this issue after 2 hours of research.

[image: nav button missing in chrome]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#geolocatecontrol:

> Not all browsers support geolocation, and some users may disable the feature. Geolocation support for modern browsers including Chrome requires sites to be served over HTTPS. If geolocation support is not available, the GeolocateControl will not be visible.